# Eliminar elementos de un combobox cargado x BD luego de comparación con otra BD VB .NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Tengo un listado de procesos productivos, y tengo un producto que sigue una serie de esos procesos asignados. Cuando cargo el formulario, lleno un combobox con los procesos, pero al seleccionar el producto que ya tiene procesos debería eliminar los procesos que ya paso y sólo mostrarme los que faltan completar o los que estan vigentes.
Se me ocurre cargar los procesos en el combo, todos y despues recorrer y obtener los procesos terminados y despues recorrer nuevamente el combobox y remover items con:

```
ComboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(codigoProceso)
```

Ahora bien, cómo tendría que hacer esa operación ?

Comment: Podrias trabajar más cómodamente con `JComboBoxModel`'s para lo que quieres hacer, o tamben con arreglos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los procesos se deberían cargar en demanda según el producto seleccionado y no de manera completa tal como lo vienes haciendo al cargar el formulario. En consecuencia, deberías poblar/enlazar el desplegable de procesos en el controlador del evento 'SelectionChangeCommitted' que se produce tras seleccionar un elemento del desplegable de productos, algo como:

```
Private Sub cbxProduct_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e ...

    cbxProcess.DisplayMember = "Process"
    cbxProcess.ValueMember = "Id"
    cbxProcess.DataSource = GetProcesses(CInt(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedValue))

End Sub
```

Finalmente, para recuperar los procesos pendientes -para el producto seleccionado- debes discriminar los que ya se encuentren asociados -entiendo en una tabla de unión, intermedia-, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT id, Process FROM Process p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Process_Product WHERE ProductId = @ProductId);
GO
```

Comment: ME SIRVIO EL SELECT, ANDUVO PERFECTO, GRACIAS